# Parametric equations including addition

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, parametric

So I am familiar with finding the parametric equation given multiplicative $x$ and $y$ values but in a problem such as

$x=2+\cos(t)$,

$y=3+\sin(t)$,

$0\le t \le \frac{5\pi}{2}$

I cannot even make of what I am supposed to do to find what type of graph this will be on nor its direction.

Comment: this is just a simple transformation$(x,y)\to(x-2,y-3)$ of $\big(x(t),y(t)\big)=\big(\cos(t),\sin(t)\big)\{0\le t\le5\pi/2\}$

Comment: It's a shifted circle is what I'm saying https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7ixjzat2r3

Comment: And to show it is a "shifted" circle, you can write $x-2=cost$ and $y-3=sint$ and square each equation. Since $sin^2t+cos^2t=1$, the equation of a circle follows

Comment: Ah yes, I have completely forgotten. So it is a unit circle not an ellipse. I was searching for a way to get denominator values.

Comment: @Computer, well, technically, any circle is also an ellipse, just not the other way around. Here it is a shifted unit circle.

Comment: What if I had an x that was equal to $cos^2t$ and a $y=cost$?

Comment: @Computer That would be a sideway parabola with vertex (0,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

community wiki post so that the question can be closed

To expand on what was said in the comments, we have
\begin{align*}
x & = 2 + \cos t\\
y & = 3 + \sin t\\
\end{align*}
where $0 \leq t \leq \frac{5\pi}{2}$.

We eliminate $t$.
\begin{align*}
x - 2 & = \cos t\\
y - 3 & = \sin t
\end{align*}
Squaring each equation and adding yields 
$$(x - 2)^2 + (y - 3)^2 = \cos^2t + \sin^2t$$
Using the Pythagorean Identity $\cos^2t + \sin^2t = 1$ yields
$$(x - 2)^2 + (y - 3)^2 = 1$$
which is the equation of a circle with radius $1$ and center $(2, 3)$.  For the entire circle to be traversed, the interval in $t$ must have length at least $2\pi$.  Since $\frac{5\pi}{2} > 2\pi$, the entire circle is traversed.  In fact, it is traversed 
$$\frac{\frac{5\pi}{2}}{2\pi} = \frac{5\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2\pi} = \frac{5}{4}$$ 
times.

[image: translated_unit_circle]